# Need to implement quiz feature

Tags: plugins

I need to implement quiz feature in which a few questions will be asked to user.

Could anyone please let me know if there is any plugin for it.

Answer (score 2):

Until the plugin store arrives, the complete list of available plugin is here:

> http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins

I don't know of any quiz plugins specifically. I did build a rudimentary quiz for a client, using only a matrix field. Depending on how you wanted to architect your quiz, a plugin may not even be necessary.